# Woocommerce - Inventory tracking based on total weight

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, inventory-management

Can I have the variable stocks deduct more than "1" unit from the parent stock?

For example. I have 10kg Total of nuts. Variable options include 1kg, 5kg, 10kg. Each weight would correspond to the correct deduction of KG's from the parent stock count.

This is the plugin I found, however it's out of date and not sure how to go about this issue!

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-variable-stock-management/

Thanks!